# newenvironment for a five-liner

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments

I am interested in a newenvironment for a five-liner (or n-liner).
My code is

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{footnpag}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in},top=1.2in,left=1.1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\newcommand{\engfont}{Noto Serif Regular}
\newcommand{\eng}[1][1.4]{
           \catcode`\^=12
            \catcode`\~=12
            \fontspec[Script=Latin,Mapping=tex-text,Scale=#1]{\engfont}}

\newenvironment{fourliner}[1]{\begingroup\setlength{\leftskip}{#1}
\parshape=4 0mm \hsize 8mm \hsize 0mm \hsize 8mm \hsize }
{\par\vspace{0.4cm}\par\endgroup}

\newenvironment{fiveliner}[1]{\begingroup\setlength{\leftskip}{#1}
\parshape=5 0mm \hsize 8mm \hsize 0mm \hsize 8mm \hsize 92mm \hsize}
{\par\vspace{0.4cm}\par\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{fiveliner}{0.0in}
{\eng Twinkle, twinkle, little star\\
How I wonder what you are\\
Up above the world so high\\
Like a diamond in the sky\\
Like a diamond in the sky\par}
\end{fiveliner}
\end{document}
```

My output is

[image]

As can be seen from the output, I have inserted 92mm for the fifth line with a hope that the fifth line is flushed right. Is there something I can add in the newenvironemnt so that I can automatically flushright whatever is the text so that the end of the fifth line aligns with the right margin.

Answer (score 1):

You can absorb the environment's content and split it at `\\`, then typeset it line by line, adding an indentation to the even-numbered lines. The last line can be detached and typeset with the larger indentation or flush right if the space would be insufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in},top=1.2in,left=1.1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\engfont}{Noto Serif Regular}[
  Script=Latin,
  Ligatures=TeX,
]
\newcommand{\eng}[1][1.4]{%
  \engfont\addfontfeatures{Scale=#1}%
  \linespread{#1}\selectfont
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{nliner}{omb}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #3 }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \par\addvspace{0.4cm}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \setlength{\leftskip}{#2}
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\eng}{\eng[#1]}
  \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \int_if_odd:nF { ##1 } { \hspace*{8mm} } ##2 \\
   }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
  \dim_compare:nTF { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box + 92mm > \columnwidth }
   {% not enough space, just fill
    \hspace*{\fill}
   }
   {% enough space
    \hspace*{92mm}
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \par\addvspace{0.4cm}
 }{}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{nliner}{0.0in}
Twinkle, twinkle, little star\\
How I wonder what you are\\
Up above the world so high\\
Like a diamond in the sky\\
Like a diamond in the sky
\end{nliner}

\begin{nliner}[2]{1cm}
Twinkle, twinkle, little star\\
How I wonder what you are\\
Up above the world so high\\
Like a diamond in the sky
\end{nliner}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can give `\leftskip` some stretch so on the last line (if you set `\parfillskip` to 0pt) it is flushed right. On the earlier lines the infinite stretch added by `\\`  ensures `\leftskip` doesn't stretch.

Make sure to add `%` at ends of lines to avoid adding white space. Also the `headheight` is too small and generates warnings but I did not fix here.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{footnpag}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in},top=1.2in,left=1.1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\newcommand{\engfont}{TeX Gyre Termes}
\newcommand{\eng}[1][1.4]{%%%%%%%
           \catcode`\^=12
            \catcode`\~=12
            \fontspec[Script=Latin,Mapping=tex-text,Scale=#1]{\engfont}}

\newenvironment{fourliner}[1]{\begingroup\setlength{\leftskip}{#1}%%%%%
\parshape=4 0mm \hsize 8mm \hsize 0mm \hsize 8mm \hsize }
{\par\vspace{0.4cm}\par\endgroup}

\newenvironment{fiveliner}[1]{%%
\setlength{\leftskip}{#1 plus 1 \textwidth}%%%
\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}%%%
\parshape=5 0mm \hsize 8mm \hsize 0mm \hsize 8mm \hsize 0mm \hsize}
{\par\vspace{0.4cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{fiveliner}{0.0in}
\eng Twinkle, twinkle, little star\\
How I wonder what you are\\
Up above the world so high\\
Like a diamond in the sky\\
Like a diamond in the sky
\end{fiveliner}
\end{document}
```